# ruby on rails bundle command error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I install rvm ( Multiuser install : \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable)
and I added user to rvm group
and I typping 'rails new testprj'
But i have an error message, It is same typping 'bundle' command errer message
How do i do?

I'm really sorry my english...

```
kitty@ubuntu:~/workspace/rails$ bundle
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mkdir': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20140211-10050-1th152x

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/sqlite3-1.3.8/gem_make.out
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `block in mktmpdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:142:in `create'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mktmpdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:14:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you add your user to the rvm group?

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE SU TO CREATE A NEW PROJECT

Sorry, but I cannot stress this enough, it's even mentioned in most guides.
The problem is Rubygems most likely.

try running the following command.

```
sudo gem update --system --no-user-install.
```

My guess is that you originally installed this somewhere in local directory which bundler cannot access. Updating the system version and setting it as default again will hopefully get you around this.